# Aims of Cinder and Swift in Openstack

Tags: openstack, volume, openstack-swift, ceph, openstack-cinder

I'm new to Openstack and I would understand very well the storage part, because I have to integrate Ceph as backend of Cinder and Swift for educational purposes ( we have to modify the crush algorithm to stress the reliability and another algorithm ti stress the performance). I've read all the tutorials, tutorials show what is an object storage and what is a block storage. 
I understand that the block storage (Cinder) is a storage for volume and the volume is attached to the vm when it is launched; and I understand that the object storage (swift) stores the images ( like cow2) of the image that are used to launch the virtual machine. 
But, do I need both block storage and object storage? The files contained in the volume are stored inside Cinder or Swift? I don't understand very well where files and other things are stored.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Swift with Nova. You can use Ceph for images and block storage with Glance and Cinder. See the following for directions: http://ceph.com/docs/master/rbd/rbd-openstack/ . Using Ceph with Nova is the easiest way to do storage.

Answer (score 0):

Swift = object storage for storing objects accessible over a rest api or http get.  This is akin to S3 at Amazon

Cinder = block storage, a volume, like a disk, or san allocation, or lvm volume.  This is like EBS in Amazon

Ceph = a suite of storage services for block, network, and object storage.

You do not need to use swift if you do not have a need for object storage -or- you can use Ceph for that purpose.

ref: https://www.mirantis.com/blog/object-storage-openstack-cloud-swift-ceph/